# iOS10: App rejected due to method called "removeEvents"

Tags: objective-c, appstore-approval, ios10, private-methods

Is there any list of methods which are not allowed when they are compiled in the application? Or a syntax that is not allowed?

With this message from Connect recently our app has been rejected due to the *removeEvents* method name:

> Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:
>
> removeEvents:
>
> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

*End. No more details regarding the finding.*

The method is used in the app on a core data object (subclassed from NSManagedObject). The object (and the method) was generated by [mogenerator app](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) for quite a long time. I did not find any reference in the updated review [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) for iOS10 that is relevant to this.

The issue is that in the rejection statement from Apple there is no private api, or a conventional object description, or any principle that I could follow to avoid this next time when the app is being approved. It is then making from the review an unpredictable process.

I could not find any trace of this method using both nm or otool. None of them has found a reference to this.

EDIT: In the iTunes Connect is an option to submit an appeal to the App Review Board. I did not noticed this before. The question is when they will review the review.

Comment: Looks like a false positive because you use a method name for your own classes that is private in one of Apple's classes. Try to respond to Apple and ask them to reconsider their decision. (I think it's related to the nature of Objective-C where the method names are visible but it's hard to tell what class it's sent to.)

Comment: I guess, they scanned the binary, and its black-listed method in any of their framework, and they just rejected it. You can ask them to review it again using iTunesConnect resolution center.

Comment: Do you have any third party dependencies that might use a method named like this?

Comment: @Codo is there any way how to file a complaint? Because the only link the message provides is the  Apple's technical support. 
I can use tool -ov myAppBinary  | sort | uniq | grep removeEvent for methods (and it is not there). Only place where this removeEvents is used is on our own subclasses of NSManagedObject. 
Thank you Adil and sandy also.

Comment: Was your app already rejected during the upload or later during the official review? If it's the former one, then I can't help you as I have no experience with it.

Comment: @Codo it was rejected later during the official review.

Comment: @Codo: No way in hell will you be able to submit an application with a method named removeEvent. It's trivial to fix, so why would they make an exception? And if you know Objective-C you will know that once I have _any_ class with a method named removeEvent, I can call that method for instances of every other class that supports it.

Comment: A lot of similar questions pop up currently, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527352/app-got-rejected-for-use-of-private-api-commenttext. It seems Apple has changed something and causes a lot of false positives. Due to the dynamic nature of Objective-C, statically checking for the use of private APIs is very imprecise. Obviously, Apple doesn't really care and rejects app anyway.

Comment: @gnasher729 The issue here is not mainly the removeEvents itself. The code has been in the app for some time, and also other app using the same code has not been rejected. Where is the list containing that information, that removeEvents method can not be submitted in the app? Thank you for adding info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A member from the review board has contacted us and confirmed that the only way to get the information about a collision with a private api is to let the app pass through the review process. Apple offered to complete a new review in two days and so they did.

I have renamed the method and the app was not rejected.

Comment: And what's the outcome of the new review?

Answer (score 0):

No more details? In that case you didn't read carefully. There will be a link to the rejection that explains exactly how to look for this if it happens in a third party library for example. Been there, done that.

So you can file a complaint and they will laugh at you, because you didn't bother reading the app rejection.

To save you the bother, search through your own source code, then use the strings and otool tools to find the library that caused the problem, update the library and check if the problem is gone.

And if you use removeEvents yourself according to your comments, then fix your code.

Comment: No more details regarding the finding I meant. Also I have written in the post that I used the tools and there was no such method listed. The removeEvents is not part of the private API as the post explains.