# App got rejected for use of private API "commentText"

Tags: ios

My app update just got rejected with this message:

> Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:
>
> commentText

I searched StackOverflow to find out how to use nm and otool to check my libraries for private APIs, but I couldn't get it to work.

Also I have a slight feeling it is a false positive since from the last update I haven't added any new third party library, only a SpriteKit minigame that only uses my code (which I'm confident has no private APIs).

Searching my project for the "commentText" string only shows some properties and methods from EBPhotoPages, a third party photo gallery which I used in previous updates as well with no problem.

Any kind of help with the nm or otool or what course of action I should take in case it actually is a false positive will be appreciated.

EDIT: Yes, I verified my app from XCode before uploading it to iTunes Connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [iOS App Rejected : non-public APIs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39405016/2415822) (I'm out of close votes).  See my answer about using `grep`, you probably have a namespace collision with a private selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commentText` is in EBPhotoPages.  I found it in the protocol `EBPhotoCommentProtocol` among other places.  Since it's on [github](https://github.com/EddyBorja/EBPhotoPages) , you should fork the repo and change it.  You should also submit a pull request to the owner with the change.

It may be failing now because it's a new symbol in the iOS 10 non-public APIs, so didn't clash previously.

As far as we can tell Apple only do a text search for their symbol names.  If they find something that matches they don't do any further analysis.